# How can I separate my output using "onclick" and format the data to 20 per page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jqgrid

How would I format the output to look something like this after entering something into a text box?

[image]

I have only gotten this to work so far:

Currently I can hit enter:

[image]

And it returns every single  "Title" in the text box:

[image]

Eventually I will update my code to return more than just the "Title" but for now it works like this:

**Javascript:**

```
function getUrl() {

$("#getUrlResult").val("");
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: "GET",
    url: "api/codes",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        data.items.forEach(function (item) {
            $("#getUrlResult").val($("#getUrlResult").val() + item.title);
        });
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Nothing Found');
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<h2>Get Data</h2>

<button onclick="getUrl()">Enter</button>

<input type="text" id="getUrlResult"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="javascripts/search.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] FilterShortUrlDto filter, string id)
{
    var su = await _repo.GetByFilter(filter); //search

    if (su == null)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(su);
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public async Task<PagedList<ShortUrl>> GetByFilter(FilterShortUrlDto filter)
{
    var fb = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<ShortUrl>();

    var fdefs = new List<FilterDefinition<ShortUrl>>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Search))
    {
        fdefs.Add(fb.Text(filter.Search));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Title))
    {
        fdefs.Add(fb.Eq(x=>x.Title, filter.Title));
    }

    int pageSize = 20, page = 1;
    int? skipCount = null;

    if (filter.PageSize == null)
    {
        pageSize = 20;
    }
    else
    {
        pageSize = filter.PageSize.Value;
    }

    if (filter.Page != null)
    {
        page = filter.Page.Value;

        if (filter.Page > 1)
        {
            skipCount = page * pageSize;
        }
    }

    var filt = fdefs.Count == 0
        ? fb.Empty
        : (fdefs.Count == 1 ? fdefs[0] : fb.Or(fdefs)); 


    var results = await _db.Urls
        .Find(filt)
        .Skip(skipCount)
        .Limit(pageSize + 1)
        .ToListAsync();

    return new PagedList<ShortUrl>(results, page, pageSize);
}
```

As you can see  I have it set up to only display 20 items per page and I am certain this is working:

[image]

My end goal is to make it easier to browse the database by limiting/organizing the data based on what is entered in that text box and outputting the data in an order/format that can be viewed by page accordingly.

**Update**

This is what my page looks like when I run:
[image]

**jqGrid:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha256-Md8eaeo67OiouuXAi8t/Xpd8t2+IaJezATVTWbZqSOw=">
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
          integrity="sha256-eZrrJcwDc/3uDhsdt61sL2oOBY362qM3lon1gyExkL0=">
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css"
          integrity="sha256-gY7w+ZzYjTPCx5Gx1YexizMJigg1YYwcQ3fAnWgAUTE=">
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="></script>
    <!-- the next line need be uncommented if you need to use bootstrap.min.js -->
    <!--<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-98vAGjEDGN79TjHkYWVD4s87rvWkdWLHPs5MC3FvFX4="></script>
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-xaF9RpdtRxzwYMWg4ldJoyPWqyDPCRD0Cv7YEEe6Ie8="></script>-->          
    <script>
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    </script>
    <script crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-GN28v8v0UEhIeH35OHeGh9LoP5liiKMRbiIFVQ5flTo="></script>
    <script>
        //<![CDATA[
        $(function () {
            "use strict";
            $("#grid1b").jqGrid({
                url: '/api/codes',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: { url: $('#grid1b').val() },
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data);
                    data.items.forEach(function (item) {
                        $("#grid1b").val($("#grid1b").val() + item.title);
                    });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Nothing Found');
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                },    
                colModel: [
                    { name: "title", label: "Title", width: 100 },
                    { name: "id", label: "Id", width: 150, template: "number" },
                    { name: "code", label: "Code", width: 150, template: "number" },    
                    { name: "originalUrl", label: "Original Url", width: 200, firstsortorder: "desc" },
                    { name: "invdate", label: "Date", width: 75, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                      formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" }
                    },
                ],    
                guiStyle: "bootstrap4",
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                idPrefix: "gb1_",
                rownumbers: true,
                sortname: "invdate",
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "Search The Database",
                headertitles: true,
                toppager: true,
                pager: true,
                rowNum: 20,
                viewrecords: true,
            }).jqGrid("filterToolbar");
        });
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<table id="grid1b"></table>
</div>
    <script src="javascripts/search.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**
I have made several changes to the code from my last update, as a result of multiple failed attempts, at getting the data to output to the jqGrid.

Following the [Demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/) suggested by my best friend DNKROZ:

[image]

I receive a couple errors:

[image]

I managed to figure out that by changing this:

```
<head>
    <!-- The jQuery library is a prerequisite for all jqSuite products -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../../../js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- We support more than 40 localizations -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../../../js/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the Javascript file of jqGrid -->   
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../../../js/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the localization file of the grid controlling messages, labels, etc.
    <!-- A link to a jQuery UI ThemeRoller theme, more than 22 built-in and many more custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <!-- The link to the CSS that the grid needs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../../css/trirand/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" />
    <script>
        $.jgrid.defaults.width = 780;
        $.jgrid.defaults.styleUI = 'Bootstrap';
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jqGrid Loading Data - JSON Live</title>
</head>
```

Into to my own updated version of the last update which looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.5/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    </script>
    <script crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-GN28v8v0UEhIeH35OHeGh9LoP5liiKMRbiIFVQ5flTo="></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-left:20px">
        <table id="jqGrid"></table>
        <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                colModel: [
                    {
                        label: 'Id',
                        name: 'id',
                        width: 150
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Title',
                        name: 'title',
                        width: 100
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Code',
                        name: 'code',
                        width: 150
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Original Url',
                        name: 'originalUrl',
                        width: 200
                    }
                ],

                viewrecords: true,
                width: 780,
                height: 200,
                rowNum: 20,
                datatype: 'JSON',
                pager: true,
                caption: "I really hope this works..."
            });

            fetchGridData();

            function fetchGridData() {

                var gridArrayData = [];
                // show loading message
                $("#jqGrid")[0].grid.beginReq();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'api/codes',
                    type: 'GET',
                    //data: JSON.stringify(result),
                    success: function (result) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
                            var item = result.items[i];
                            gridArrayData.push({
                                id: item.id,
                                title: item.title,
                                code: item.code,
                                originalUrl: item.originalUrl,
                            });
                        }
                        // set the new data
                        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: gridArrayData });
                        // hide the show message
                        $("#jqGrid")[0].grid.endReq();
                        // refresh the grid
                        $("#jqGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The warning goes away and my output now looks like this:

[image]

I could be wrong but I do believe my controller action is returning JSON data and here is my understanding of why:

When using Postman to test my code I 'get' JSON back:

[image]

Even though my get function doesn't "return Json(su);" like so:

[image]

Also while looking through the database collection using Robo 3T I noticed when right clicking there is an option to "Copy Json":

[image]

Correct me if I am wrong as I am still new to MongoDb / Asp.net Core but I do believe that it is working on that end I just am not sure about the jqGrid.

**Update:**

I had to add a few files from [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php).

[image]

Also need this:

[image]

Also had to add "hiddengrid: true" AND call "fetchGridData();" after the function (for some reason) like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.5/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    </script>
    <script crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-GN28v8v0UEhIeH35OHeGh9LoP5liiKMRbiIFVQ5flTo="></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/styles3.css" />
    <script src="javascripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center" id="overGrid">
        <table id="jqGrid"></table>
        <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'api/codes',
                editurl: 'api/codes',
                colModel: [
                    {
                        label: "Edit Actions",
                        name: "actions",
                        width: 75,
                        formatter: "actions",
                        formatoptions: {
                            keys: true,
                            editOptions: {},
                            addOptions: {},
                            delOptions: {}
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Id',
                        name: 'id',
                        width: 150,
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Title',
                        name: 'title',
                        width: 100,
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Code',
                        name: 'code',
                        width: 100,
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Original Url',
                        name: 'originalUrl',
                        width: 200,
                        editable: true
                    }
                ],
                align: 'center',
                viewrecords: true,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                width: 925,
                height: 445,
                rowNum: 20,
                loadonce: true,
                hiddengrid: true,
                toppager: '#jqGridPager',
                pager: '#jqGridPager',
                caption: "Database"

            }); jQuery("#jqGrid")
                .navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false })
                .navButtonAdd('#pager', {
                    caption: "Add",
                    buttonicon: "ui-icon-add",
                    onClickButton: function () {
                        alert("Adding Row");
                    },
                    position: "last"
                })
                .navButtonAdd('#pager', {
                    caption: "Del",
                    buttonicon: "ui-icon-del",
                    onClickButton: function () {
                        alert("Deleting Row");
                    },
                    position: "last"
                });

            function fetchGridData() {    
                var gridArrayData = [];
                // show loading message
                $("#jqGrid")[0].grid.beginReq();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'api/codes',
                    mtype: 'POST',
                    datatype: 'JSON',
                    success: function (result) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
                            var item = result.items[i];
                            gridArrayData.push({
                                id: item.id,
                                title: item.title,
                                code: item.code,
                                originalUrl: item.originalUrl,
                            });
                        }
                        // set the new data
                        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: gridArrayData });
                        // hide the show message
                        $("#jqGrid")[0].grid.endReq();
                        // refresh the grid
                        $("#jqGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');    
                    }
                });
            }    
            fetchGridData();    
        });     
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Now the output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Create a table in your view, then use razor to loop through your results and create a `tr` for each row, use your model properties to set the column text

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using views/razor.

Comment: Then you could just a plugin such as JQGrid which allows you to turn a simple html table definition into a fully paged table, using a JSON result from your action.
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs

Comment: YES, this looks promising! Wish this site had "friending" capabilities because you just became my best friend.

Comment: haha I can write you an answer and you can up vote if you like!

Comment: Yes absolutely, I sincerely appreciate the useful information friend!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using razor, I'd recommend taking a look at some JavaScript plugins which are able to generate grids.

I currently use one called jqGrid which can be customized pretty easily and is quite simple to get working with paging. It basically works by receiving a JSON result from your controller action and generates a grid from the HTML table element that you attached it to.

Here's a link to the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php)

Here's a [demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/)

Comment: I have gotten the grid to show up but I have been unable to get any data to show up. I will update my question up above if care to take a crack at it.

Comment: I don't think you need the `data` attribute, the `url` attribute should be the URL to your controller action, which should return data as JSON and the properties should match exactly those of `colModel` `name`. Are you sure your controller action is returning JSON data?

Comment: Your controller action needs to be returning a `JsonResult` see this example https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-JsonResult-example-Return-JSON-data-from-Controller-to-View-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: In order to avoid any confusion I thought it would be easier if I answered your questions by updating the post above. Seriously thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: The only thing I can really suggets is try changing your controller action return type to a JSON Result, although you're right it does look like it's already returning valid JSON. I'm not sure what else I can help you with so you might be better off posting another question just relating to the jqGrid, there's a few active users who actually helped build this plugin which have helped me a lot in the past!

Comment: Thank for your help, I managed to solve my problem. I'll provide an update of what I did above.

Comment: Ohh I didn't even think of mentioning the scripts haha! Glad you found a solution anyway, glad to help