# Why won't data output to jqGrid without the use of "hiddengrid: true"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I want this:

[image]

Without having to start like this:

[image]

But for some reason the data only shows up when I use "hiddengrid: true,"

I tried following this [demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/loading_data/json_web/index.html) and was only able to get the example to work by adding "hiddengrid: true," like so:

```
<body>
<div class="center" id="overGrid">
    <table id="jqGrid"></table>
    <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'api/codes',
            editurl: 'api/codes',
            colModel: [
                {
                    label: "Edit Actions",
                    name: "actions",
                    width: 75,
                    formatter: "actions",
                    formatoptions: {
                        keys: true,
                        editOptions: {},
                        addOptions: {},
                        delOptions: {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Id',
                    name: 'id',
                    width: 150,
                    editable: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Title',
                    name: 'title',
                    width: 100,
                    editable: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Code',
                    name: 'code',
                    width: 100,
                    editable: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Original Url',
                    name: 'originalUrl',
                    width: 200,
                    editable: true
                }
            ],
            align: 'center',
            viewrecords: true,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            width: 925,
            height: 445,
            rowNum: 20,
            loadonce: true,
            hiddengrid: true, // <-------------------- HERE
            toppager: '#jqGridPager',
            pager: '#jqGridPager',
            caption: "Database"

        }); jQuery("#jqGrid")
            .navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false })
            .navButtonAdd('#pager', {
                caption: "Add",
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-add",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    alert("Adding Row");
                },
                position: "last"
            })
            .navButtonAdd('#pager', {
                caption: "Del",
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-del",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    alert("Deleting Row");
                },
                position: "last"
            });

        function fetchGridData() {

            var gridArrayData = [];
            // show loading message
            $("#jqGrid")[0].grid.beginReq();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api/codes',
                mtype: 'POST',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                success: function (result) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
                        var item = result.items[i];
                        gridArrayData.push({
                            id: item.id,
                            title: item.title,
                            code: item.code,
                            originalUrl: item.originalUrl,
                        });
                    }
                    // set the new data
                    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: gridArrayData });
                    // hide the show message
                    $("#jqGrid")[0].grid.endReq();
                    // refresh the grid
                    $("#jqGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
                }
            });
        }
        fetchGridData();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Examples such as [this](http://dcm.ujf-grenoble.fr/lib-new/guriddo/jqgridjs/loading_data/json_web/index.html) don't seem to be working for me on their own so I keep having to reference other sources such as [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/jqgrid-rest-ajax-spring-mvc-integration.html) that are much more complex and informative but possibly the reason for why I continue to have issues every step of the way.

**Side Note**

I should probably point out that I was only just recently introduced to jqGrid as a result of this question I asked about a week ago: " [How can I separate my output using “onclick” and format the data to 20 per page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972972/how-can-i-separate-my-output-using-onclick-and-format-the-data-to-20-per-page)
 "

I did a fairly decent job of documenting the steps that brought me to this point so it might be worth checking out for an in depth look as to what I am dealing with.

In short I am building an API in Asp.Net Core that sends and receives JSON data to my MongoDb database and then outputs the data to a single HTML page using jqGrid. So far I have created functioning Get, Post, Put, and Delete methods that return and send JSON data to my MongoDb database.

**Update:**

I have gone through the docs suggested by Tony Tomov and I understand their meaning. I just haven't the slightest clue to the solution to this problem. Everything I have thought to be a possible solution and tried from before and after I posted this question has given me a blank page without any errors.

Comment: Did you have look at the docs what this option mean? Maybe it will help. [Here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#options) you can read about it.

Comment: Thanks, this was a helpful resource that I had initially appreciated reading but I must confess that after a couple hours of reading through it, and attempting what I thought would be the simple fix, I ended up following a few  different "working" examples that were far different then mine and eventually led me to rewriting my controllers to make it "easier" to follow. This of course resulted in failure and reverting back to my original code. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!